# Odd lines appearing under images

Tags: bug, status-completed

On questions and answers with an image, I'm noticing that there's a line placed under the image:

[American "Bacon Roll" - what is it?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/59577/american-bacon-roll-what-is-it)

[image: Line Under image]

And here:

[Watermelon - picking and managing them during heat](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/59482/watermelon-picking-and-managing-them-during-heat/59483#59483)

[image: Line under image]

I've not noticed this occurring on other sites.

It happens in both FF and Chrome.

Comment: I just want to let you know it's happening on Safari on iPad too!

Comment: Looks like this was fixed by [the design update](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/a-design-update-is-coming)!

Comment: @Jefromi YAY! Indeed, you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

That's just how it's always looked when you make a link on an image. The dotted line is the same as for text links, except for some reason displaced a line below the image. I agree it doesn't look great, and I'd love if they fixed it, but it's not a total accident.

Comment: I haven't looked at the Site Design Meta post from when they released the design to see if the issue has always been the case (and I'm not even sure the site design meta post would show it, to be honest). It seems that when they update things, it sometimes fubars stuff. It may be long-standing but making it go away would be awesome! :D

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that this issue **does not** exist in Meta!